# Python: how could this image be properly segmented?

Tags: python, scikit-image

I would like to segment (isolate) the rod-like structures shown in this image:

[image]

The best I've managed to do is this

```
# Imports the libraries.
from skimage import io, filters
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Imports the image as a numpy array.
img = io.imread('C:/Users/lopez/Desktop/Test electron/test.tif')

# Thresholds the images using a local threshold.
thresh = filters.threshold_local(img,301,offset=0)
binary_local = img > thresh # Thresholds the image
binary_local = np.invert(binary_local) # inverts the thresholded image (True becomes False and vice versa).

# Shows the image.
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.imshow(binary_local,cmap='Greys')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Which produces this result

[image]

However, as you can see from the segmented image, I haven't managed to isolate the rods. What should be black background is filled with interconnected structures. Is there a way to neatly isolate the rod-like structures from all other elements in the image?

The original image can be downloaded from this website

https://dropoff.nbi.ac.uk/pickup.php

Claim ID: qMNrDHnfEn4nPwB8

Claim Passcode: UkwcYoYfXUfeDto8

Comment: Can you include a link to the source image? Downloading and using it with your code causes errors.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your comment. I've edited the original post. I've added a link to the raw image at the bottom.

Comment: Look into hough line transforms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my attempt using a Meijering filter. The Meijering filter relies on symmetry when it looks for tubular structures and hence the regions where rods overlap (breaking the symmetry of the tubular shape) are not that well recovered, as can be seen in the overlay below.

Also, there is some random crap that I have trouble getting rid off digitally, but maybe you can clean your prep a bit more before imaging.

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from skimage.io import imread
from skimage.transform import rescale
from skimage.restoration import denoise_nl_means
from skimage.filters import meijering
from skimage.measure import label
from skimage.color import label2rgb


def remove_small_objects(binary_mask, size_threshold):
    label_image = label(binary_mask)
    object_sizes = np.bincount(label_image.ravel())
    labels2keep, = np.where(object_sizes > size_threshold)
    labels2keep = labels2keep[1:] # remove the first label, which corresponds to the background
    clean = np.in1d(label_image.ravel(), labels2keep).reshape(label_image.shape)
    return clean


if __name__ == '__main__':

    raw = imread('test.tif')
    raw -= raw.min()
    raw /= raw.max()

    # running everything on the large image took too long for my patience;
    raw = rescale(raw, 0.25, anti_aliasing=True)

    # smooth image while preserving edges
    smoothed = denoise_nl_means(raw, h=0.05, fast_mode=True)

    # filter for tubular shapes
    sigmas = range(1, 5)
    filtered = meijering(smoothed, sigmas=sigmas, black_ridges=False)
    # Meijering filter always evaluates to high values at the image frame;
    # we hence set the filtered image to zero at those locations
    frame = np.ones_like(filtered, dtype=np.bool)
    d = 2 * np.max(sigmas) + 1 # this is the theoretical minimum ...
    d += 2 # ... but doesn't seem to be enough so we increase d
    frame[d:-d, d:-d] = False
    filtered[frame] = np.min(filtered)

    thresholded = filtered > np.percentile(filtered, 80)
    cleaned = remove_small_objects(thresholded, 200)

    overlay = raw.copy()
    overlay[np.invert(cleaned)] = overlay[np.invert(cleaned)] * 2/3

    fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 3, sharex=True, sharey=True)
    axes = axes.ravel()
    axes[0].imshow(raw, cmap='gray')
    axes[1].imshow(smoothed, cmap='gray')
    axes[2].imshow(filtered, cmap='gray')
    axes[3].imshow(thresholded, cmap='gray')
    axes[4].imshow(cleaned, cmap='gray')
    axes[5].imshow(overlay, cmap='gray')

    for ax in axes:
        ax.axis('off')

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.imshow(overlay, cmap='gray')
    ax.axis('off')
    plt.show()
```

[image]

If this code makes it into a paper, I want an acknowledgement and a copy of the paper. ;-)